# Magento 2, address->getRegion() return object instead of string

Tags: magento2, customer-address

**I'm trying to get Region from shipping address.**
Here's the code :

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->get('xxx@xxx.com');
$shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
$shippingAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById($shippingAddressId);
$shippingAddress->getRegion();
```

**But I'm not getting string of region name**, instead I **got Object** from  `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region`

The country is not United States, so Region is simply string ( input text form ) instead of select, so **no Region Id / Region Code** when I created the customer from admin.

So, how correct way to get Region from shipping when there are no region id / region code?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to look inside `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region`, and inside it there is a code :

```
/**
     * Get region
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRegion()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::REGION);
    }
```

So I use `$shippingAddress->getRegion()->getRegion();` to get correct region name.

Still, the code look kinda weird, and I hope there are more answer to just use `$shippingAddress->getRegion()` and got the string of region name i need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to get Region from default shipping addresss

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
)
{
    ...
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getRegion() {
    $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
    if ($customer) {
        $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
        if ($shippingAddress) {
            return $shippingAddress->getRegion();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```